# Prove Hessian is positive definite thus the stationary point is a local minimizer?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, positive-definite

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda>0,$ set
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}||Ax-b||^2_2+\frac{\lambda}{2}||x||^2_2$$

Easily I found

$\nabla f(x) = A^T(Ax-b) + \lambda x$

and

$\nabla^2 f(x) = A^TA +\lambda$.

Therefore, setting $\nabla f(x) = A^T(Ax-b) + \lambda x = 0,$ I have a stataionary point of $f(x)$

$x = \frac{A^Tb}{A^TA+\lambda}$

Now, how  do I prove that the stationary point is a local minimizer?

What I tried is:

Using the sufficient conditions, if $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is PD, then the stationary point is a local minimizer.

Thus, how do I prove  $\nabla^2 f(x)$ is PD for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you know that $A^TA$ is nonnegative definite?

Comment: Yes, $A^TA$ is positive-semi definite. But for this problem it seems I need to prove that hessian is PD.

Comment: But you have that $\lambda I$ and $\lambda >0$.

Comment: Oh, then is it simply that since $\lambda>0$, $A^TA+\lambda I$ is independent of $x$, so all eigenvalues of $A^TA+ \lambda I$ are positive?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks! It just makes so much sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127354/discussion-between-jayden-rice-and-arctic-char).

Comment: Prove that if $x\neq 0$ then $x^T(A^T A + \lambda I) x > 0$.